# How to convert a single animated webp with a transparent background to an animated gif using imagemagick, with disposing of prior frames?

Tags: imagemagick, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert, webp

I have an animated WebP with a transparent background ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EazcmJ1QMHZbWVxfK2LTunb0fnzNEwtb/view?usp=sharing)).

Running `magick -dispose previous .\image.webp .\image.gif` (or `-dispose background`) does not dispose of the previous frame, resulting in the following:

[image: flamingo with a gun, gif]

What is the correct way to convert an animated WebP to an animated gif, ideally with `convert`, while keeping the background clear each frame?

Comment: Please share the input image in Webp format (maybe via Google Drive or Dropbox) or a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-coalesce`:

`convert -dispose previous -coalesce flamingun.webp flamingun.gif`
[image: Fixed image]